# Gathering Data from a Checked Row in a numbered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, websmart

As an RPG pgm for 25+yrs I have been working with JavaScript & JQuery for about 16months & mostly by copying & trial & error.
The issue I am having is probably very basic for many but I can't see the forest for the trees, I suppose.
I've written the script & HTML as simply as I could:
I have an "approval" checkbox on a LIST that is pre-populated by a flag in the dbfile being read & displayed in the numbered ("x") list.
If the empty checkbox is checked I want to update the flag for that row.  I am using the following (without success) to gather the 3 key fields (from the list) I will need to do the update.
I am hitting the alerts but they read "Undefined" or show NO data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //Jquery for Test-Drive approval
        $(".ApproveTD").click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) { // checked
                alert("This is TD UPDATE");
                var td_id = $(this).attr("td_id");
                var CMCONO = $("#CMCONO_" + td_id).val();
                var CMPGMN = $("#CMPGMN_" + td_id).val();
                var CMDEALER = $("#CMDEALER_" + td_id).val();

                alert("This is TD UPDATE: " + CMCONO + "/" + CMPGMN + "/" + CMDEALER);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "<field name=pgmf_qpgmnam>",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "task": "ajax_apptd",
                        "ajax_checked": 'Y',
                        "CMCONO_": CMCONO,
                        "CMPGMN_": CMPGMN,
                        "CMDEALER_": CMDEALER
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Here is some of the HTML in question:

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="ApproveTD" id="<field name=x>" type="checkbox" name="<field name=CMATDDSM>" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="x" value="<field name=x>" />
            <input type="hidden" id="CMCONO_<field name=x>" value="<field name=CMCONO>" />
            <input type="hidden" id="CMPGMN_<field name=x>" value="<field name=CMPGMN>" />
            <input type="hidden" id="CMDEALER_<field name=x>" value="<field name=CMDEALER>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: this is a challenging post to follow because the fields names are weird and look like html. I created a fiddle and renamed the html elements to something that people can follow. Maybe you can review it and edit the elements if need. This will help you get to a solution. http://jsfiddle.net/jyL37/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for your help but I got it squared away...

The HTML id field during the run was ex:  CMCONO_00001
while the concatenated script var was ex: CMCONO_1.

==============

To correct I edited the HTML "x" so the parameter names now match!